# How can I stop objects from disappearing?

Tags: buildbox

I'm developing a game with Buildbox and I'm facing a problem that I have no idea how to solve.
In practice I am making a vertical scrolling game where you can only go up. An endless climb in which to avoid obstacles, traps and so on.
To move the gameplay a little, I decided to insert a pinball section in which to hit objects with a ball to break free and continue the climb. The problem I have concerns the levers to hit the ball.

If I try the stage individually there are no problems, but if I pass the stage to come back again and continue the game normally, the sticks tend to disappear after a couple of interactions with them.

[image]

The yellow points are the levers, the blue points are the triggers that bring the levers back to the starting position if they should go out of place

I have already tried the following solutions:

- Add a spawner command, but the result is a constant spawn of the stick in the starting position compared to what I need. Even if the lever receives interaction or command to move.
- Tie the lever to other fixed elements of the scenario, but the result is that the lever does not move, rightly.
- Tie the lever to other movable elements of the scenario.
- Increase the back and side deletion threshold.
- Cancel and redo the levers.

I noticed that the levers disappeared because I moved them while passing from one stage to another. They disappeared because the button to make the character jump is superimposed on the one to move the levers. I made sure that the buttons did not interpenetrate, but nothing changed, the only thing I got is that the levers are not already gone when I return to the stage, but that they disappear as soon as I move them again.

I also tried to remove the triggers, but the levers do a thousand turns on themselves and then disappear anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid using third party services to show images. If you need to add images, add them to the post by either clicking the image button while editing, or copying the image and clicking CTRL+V, or in any other way pasting it) directly into the post. Third party image services [can break at any time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354950/6296561), and either leave a dead link, or the URLs can be used for malicious purposes.